# Do I have to re-query the DOM to get the jQuery selector within .blur()?

Tags: jquery

I've searched a bit, but I'm not sure how to write the question to find the answer I want.

Given the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('input').blur(function(e){
  //can i get $('input') from within e?
  $('input').val('');
});
```

How can I re-use the `$('input')` selector - typically it's available within `this` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your callback `this` is the dom element and `$(this)` is the jQueryified dom element.

Unless you're using e somewhere else I think this would work:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
  $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: Thank you - it was confusing to differentiate between `this` and jQueryified `this`

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how `this` works in jQuery:

```
$(this).val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andy mentioned, `this`, refers to the DOM element the event occurred on. No need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object to get the value though:

```
$('input').blur(function(e){
    this.value = '';
});
```

Using `$(this)` in this case is unnecessary, if all you're doing is setting the value.